# Counting a full rotation with a circular drive

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, steamvr

I've been raking my brain for the last day on how to calculate a full rotation with how to count a full rotation of an object along the X axis thats using the base circular drive from SteamVR.

I thought a simple 3d cube, with the mesh turned off in the the path of the rotation with collision code on it would be a barebone way of doing it, but it doesn't even seem to be registering the detection when the object hits the placed cubes, and i know its not because of me being stupid, as its recycled code from a working part of the project.

Below i have a small piece of code that basically detects when the object has reached the end of the rotation, and then increments the Count by one.

My main problem is that sometimes it manages to clock more than once, and if you can find the right spot, you can just keep it there and it'll keep on adding the count up by. Im wondering how i can stop it and increment only by one, until another full rotation has been made?

EDIT: to be more clear in case there is any confusion, Once the angle is clocked in between 359 and 360, i want it to increment once, whereas currently if you get the angle to sit anywhere in between 359-360 it will carry on adding one to the rotation count, despite no full rotation having been made, so im trying to figure out how to make my code only increment once, and once it does increment once it resets the position to zero, so therefore no more Increments can happen. It's a crank mechanism in VR, along the X axis.

Any help is appreciated, Thanks!

```
 float Test;

float RotationCount = 0;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
   //  Test = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x;


}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (Test > 359 && Test < 360)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clocked");
        count();
    }
    else
    {
      //  Debug.Log("Nope");
    }


    if (Test == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Yes");
    }

    Test = transform.localRotation.eulerAngles.x;

}

void count()
{

    RotationCount++;

}
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using. Currently I don't fully understand what you are asking.

Comment: @derHugo Hi, i just added the code in now, sorry about that

Comment: Thanks I still don't understand what exactly you are trying to archieve there. to `sometimes it manages to clock more than once, and if you can find the right spot, you can just keep it there and it'll keep on adding the count up by.` ... think about what is happening if your angle is e.g. `359.5` or better said any floating point value that is `359 > x < 360`. Also `Test == 0` might never be true

Comment: @derHugo sorry Test == 0 was just my way of seeing if it was working at the beginning. Sorry i'll try to be more clear, once the angle is clocked in between 359 and 360, i want it to increment once, and then in order to be able to increment the count again, it has to go from 0 - 359-360 yet again, as right now if you manage to put it at anywhere between 359-360 it'll keep increment. It's a crank mechanism in VR, along the X axis, so im trying to find a way that after 3 'legitimate' rotations, it performs an action. But im stuck on the counting real rotations part. Is that better?

Answer (score 0):

> sometimes it manages to clock more than once, and if you can find the right spot, you can just keep it there and it'll keep on adding the count up by.

well in

```
if (Test > 359 && Test < 360)
{
    Debug.Log("Clocked");
    count();
}
```

what happens if your angle is e.g. `359.5`?

It is very difficult to just take a current rottaion and know whether it was turned more or less than a certain angle.

---

I'ld rather store the last rotation, compare it to the current one and add the difference to a variable. Than if the variable exceeds `360` a full rotation was done. Since I also don't like to calculate anything with `Quaternion` and `eulerAngles`, way simplier is to use the methods provided by `Vector3`.

For the local rotation around `X` (== `transform.right`) I would use the angle between the current and the last `transfrm.up` vector.

Something like

```
public class RotationCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int RotationCount;

    public float rotatedAroundX;

    public Vector3 lastUp;

    public UnityEvent On3TimesRotated;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rotatedAroundX = 0;

        // initialize
        lastUp = transform.up;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        var rotationDifference = Vector3.SignedAngle(transform.up, lastUp, transform.right);

        rotatedAroundX += rotationDifference;

        if (rotatedAroundX >= 360.0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("One positive rotation done", this);

            RotationCount++;

            rotatedAroundX -= 360.0f;
        }
        else if (rotatedAroundX <= -360.0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("One negative rotation done", this);

            RotationCount--;

            rotatedAroundX += 360.0f;
        }

        // update last rotation
        lastUp = transform.up;


        // check for fire the event
        if (RotationCount >= 3)
        {
            On3TimesRotated?.Invoke();

            RotationCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a [UnityEvent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Events.UnityEvent.html) to get the same thing the `Button` uses for `onClick` so you can reference callbacks there via the inspector.

[image]

---

**BUT** if you don't care about the single rotations but actually only wnat the final `RotationCount >= 3` I would actually use

```
private void Update()
{
    var rotationDifference = Vector3.SignedAngle(transform.up, lastUp, transform.right);

    rotatedAroundX += rotationDifference;

    RotationCount = Mathf.RoundToInt(rotatedAroundX / 360.0f);

    // update last rotation
    lastUp = transform.up;


    // check for fire the event
    if (RotationCount >= 3)
    {
        On3TimesRotated?.Invoke();

        RotationCount = 0;
        rotatedAroundX = 0;
    }
}
```

which directly reduces the value by one if rotated under the 360 mark instead of waiting for a full negative rotation

[image]

*as you can see instead of reaching 3 the `RotationCount` is reset to 0. This is where the `On3TimesRotated` event is/would get fired.

Comment: im getting this error; `error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UnityEvent' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` from line 9 `public UnityEvent On3TimesRotated;`

Comment: `using UnityEngine.Events;` ;)

Comment: Hi since adding that, it seems to break my whole VR setup? is there a way to not use `UnityEngine.Events`? i tried multiple times, and as soon as i added that line in, it seemed to break the whole VR setup i had. EDIT: seems to have just been my unity being buggy, i restarted my computer and somehow that fixed it i think, i'll post another comment in a second once ive tested out the code, thanks!

Comment: Yes ofcourse you can also complete remove that event and instead simply call a usual method there :) I just thought you might want to use it similar to the Button.onClick where you simply can define in the editor what should happen. But ofcourse if it's not working you could simply call any method there instead.

Comment: i just tried it, and its absolutely perfect thank you so much, i havent been able to get a good working version of this before, its amazing thank you for the help